# removing character substring to be used in merging two datasets in r

Tags: r

I have two data sets to be compared for their similarity, say hapmap.table and thousand_genomes.table. I'm searching and retrieving similar records with merge() function. But in hapmap file chromosome number is entered as chr1 , chr2 etc, while other represents only as a number. How can I get rid of the character chr from the whole dataset before merging, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming chrom is the chromosome number column in hapmap.table

```
gsub("^chr","",hapmap.table$chrom)
```

Example:

```
hh<-structure(list(hh = structure(1:3, .Label = c("chr12", "chr23", 
"chr45"), class = "factor")), .Names = "hh", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

 hh
     hh
1 chr12
2 chr23
3 chr45

hh$hh<- gsub("^chr","",hh$hh)

 hh
  hh
1 12
2 23
3 45
```